# trace python: only include some files

Tags: python, debugging, trace

I know that I can use this to trace the command execution:

```
python -m trace -t script.py
```

But I want to reduce the output: Only files which are in my src/ (pip install -e ...) should be shown.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My solution is based on the answer of Brian Cain:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
python -m trace --ignore-dir=$HOME/lib64:$HOME/lib:/usr -t script.py
```

My virtualenv is directly in $HOME and my code is installed editable in $HOME/src.

This `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8;` is needed since I got UnicodeErrors if there where non ascii characters in the python code.

Comment: Note that it's necessary to specify `ignore-dir` *before* the script name, otherwise it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 24):

If you are running script from `bash` you can use something like:

```
python -m trace --ignore-dir=$(python -c 'import sys ; print ":".join(sys.path)[1:]') -t ./script.py
```

for python3:

```
python -m trace --ignore-dir=$(python -c 'import sys ; print(":".join(sys.path)[1:])') -t ./script.py
```

In this way you can ignore if you are or not in a virtual environment or a more esoteric scenario.

Comment: I always use virtualenv, for me it is not esoteric :-) but you solution is a good hint how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: I agree, 'esoteric' was just for other scenarios :-).

Comment: This works, but you meant `join(sys.path[1:])` I think :-)

Comment: @MayraDelgado I meant what I wrote (cut away the first character) that has the same effect of yours (that is, I agree, conceptually more clear and correct ;) )

Comment: I had to change each `python` to `python3` to get this to work

Comment: It also helps if you pipe the output to `less` then look for non code lines with `/!:` then scroll with `n` and `p`

Answer (score 4):

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) states, you can use `trace` programatically:

```
import sys
import trace

# create a Trace object, telling it what to ignore, and whether to
# do tracing or line-counting or both.
tracer = trace.Trace(
    ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
    trace=0,
    count=1)

# run the new command using the given tracer
tracer.run('main()')

# make a report, placing output in the current directory
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(show_missing=True, coverdir=".")
```

Note the `ignoredirs` argument to `trace.Trace`.

While there doesn't seem to be a way to explicitly include only files in your `src`, you can exclude all system packages, which, for practical purposes, should be the same.

Comment: I thought this solution send the results to a file, but it actually prints to stdout, awesome

Comment: You don't need the `write_results` part.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to reduce the output

There's no whitelist filter, but there is a blacklist:

[`ignore_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html#cmdoption-trace--ignore-module):

> --ignore-module= Ignore each of the given module names and its submodules (if it is a package). The argument can be a list of names
>   separated by a comma.