# Use python module trace through Shebang

Tags: python, python-2.4

I am working on an environment where I have to call my python script by itself  : `./myscript.py` instead of `python-2.4 -m trace -t /myscript.py`.

So , I try to add arguments in the shebang like below :

```
#!/usr/bin/python-2.4 -m trace -t

print "HELLO"

print "HW"
```

But I got the error message below :

`/usr/bin/python-2.4: module  trace -t not found`

Is it possible in Python ? I don't want to handle this trace module inside my script.

Comment: Out of curiosity what sort of system are you working on that has a 13 year old version of Python and that you have to run your file directly without using the interpreter name inside the shell itself?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working on web application which handle only python 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to do this simply on most platforms, particularly Linux.  The POSIX standard only requires that a single command line option be supported by the shebang.  This can mean that the arguments are truncated, but it can also lead to all of the options being passed as a single option, as though they were contained in quotation marks.

The simplest way to achieve this is to create an additional wrapper.  For example:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 /usr/bin/python-2.4 -m trace -t ./myscript.py
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use shell scripts on the environment , only python 2.4 is available.

Comment: @madago You can call shell commands from Python as well. `os.system` or `subprocess.call`.

Comment: Alternatively [use `trace` programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25667278/5267751).